# Why does MatchIt can calculate mean on a factor column?

Tags: categorical-data, matching

I assume that it is not possible to calculate a `mean()` from a `factor()` column with three expressions.

But it seems to me that R's MatchIt package is able to do that. Please see this summary output which reports a mean for all three expressions of the factor column `race`:

```
Summary of Balance for Matched Data:
           Means Treated Means Control Std. Mean Diff. Var. Ratio eCDF Mean eCDF Max Std. Pair Dist.
distance          0.5661        0.2111          1.6809     0.7758    0.3466   0.6189          1.6821
age              25.8162       28.9541         -0.4386     0.4006    0.1051   0.2027          1.4887
raceblack         0.8432        0.2351          1.6726          .    0.6081   0.6081          1.6726
racehispan        0.0595        0.1649         -0.4457          .    0.1054   0.1054          0.8114
racewhite         0.0973        0.6000         -1.6962          .    0.5027   0.5027          1.7327
married           0.1892        0.4351         -0.6280          .    0.2459   0.2459          0.8350
```

This is the minimal working example to reproduce this:

```
library("MatchIt")
data("lalonde")

# simplify
lalonde = lalonde[,c("treat", "age", "race", "married")]

# 2:1 matching
m.out <- matchit(
    treat ~ age + race + married,
    data = lalonde,
    method = "nearest",
    distance = "glm",
    ratio = 2
)
summary(m.out)
```

Again I am sure that the `race` column is a factor with only three expressions:

```
> table(lalonde$race)

black hispan  white
243     72    299

> class(lalonde$race)
[1] "factor"
```

I am not able to calculate a mean by myself on that column

```
> mean(lalonde$race)
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(lalonde$race) :
  Argument ist weder numerisch noch boolesch: gebe NA zurück
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For categorical variables, [MatchIt](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MatchIt/index.html) reports the proportion of observations in each category, separately for the treated and the controls. For binary variables, it reports the proportion of `1`s. To verify, check that `raceblack + racehispan + racewhite` sum up to 1 in the `Treated` and `Control` columns.

If a random variable takes two values {0, 1}, then $\operatorname{E}\{X\} = \operatorname{Pr}\{X=1\}$. So MatchIt computes the means of one-hot encoded (dummy) indicators, one for each level of a categorical variable.